# Change CSS on active button with varied class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a variety of buttons in the navigation bar of my website that I would like to do a few things on click:

```
1. Open an overlay relative to the button pressed
2. Close any other open overlays
3. Add a border to the button until that button's related overlay is closed.
```

My navigation bar looks something like this:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="signup_btn">Sign Up</div>
    <div class="login_btn">Login</div>
</div>
```

Here's the overlay html:

```
<div class="signup_overlay">
    <!-- FORM HERE -->
</div>
<div class="login_overlay">
    <!-- FORM HERE -->
</div>
```

and the JQuery to extend the overlays/close others:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.signup_btn').click(function() {
    $('.login_overlay').hide();
    $('.signup_overlay').slideToggle( 300 );
});

$('.login_btn').click(function() {
    $('.signup_overlay').hide();
    $('.login_overlay').slideToggle( 300 );
});
</script>
```

As I add more buttons to the navigation bar, I feel as if theres a lot of unnecessary CSS for each individual button, so that the JQuery can get the correct element. Is there a cleaner, more efficient way to do this?

Also, to add the border to the bottom of the button related to the current overlay, should this all be done with Javascript, or is there a clean/not repetitive way of doing it with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a common class to all the trigger elements and the overlays and then write a single handle as below

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="signup_btn btn" data-target=".signup_overlay">Sign Up</div>
    <div class="login_btn btn" data-target=".login_overlay">Login</div>
</div>
<div class="signup_overlay overlay">signup_overlay</div>
<div class="login_overlay overlay">login_overlay</div>
```

then

```
$('#navbar .btn').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('.overlay').not(target).hide();
    $(target).slideToggle(300);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TLg7M/)

Answer (score 2):

> As I add more buttons to the navigation bar, I feel as if theres a lot of unnecessary CSS for each individual button, so that the JQuery can get the correct element. Is there a cleaner, more efficient way to do this?

It depends, as long as you remember that the main purpose of CSS is to provide styles to HTML elements, if you remember this when design and planning your approach then there's nothing wrong with what your doing.

What I mean is that if your buttons required a different style each, then that's the most straight-forward way to go. However, if you are assigning different CSS classes to your buttons for the mere purpose of marking/identifying each buttons so that jQuery target specific buttons then that's wrong...it'll work but it'll look like a code smell to anyone with a bit of design skills. What you can do is...

1. Assign different `id`s to the buttons and select them by id

   `$("#element_id);`
2. Add a custom data attribute, you can name it whatever you want, for example

and then use unobtrusive javascript to select them

```
$("[data-field=login]")
```

> Also, to add the border to the bottom of the button related to the current overlay, should this all be done with Javascript, or is there a clean/not repetitive way of doing it with CSS?

This is best done with CSS rather than javascript if you set `display:absolute` to your overlays. You can also give them a `z-index` to sit on top of other elements

Answer (score 1):

You could use one button class that has the same styling for all buttons and give each button an individual id that would be referenced in your jquery.

For example:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="btn" id="signup_btn">Sign Up</div>
    <div class="btn" id="login_btn">Login</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For your border issue; take a look at the :active selector http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/

Comment: I thought about that, but wouldn't the CSS changes immediately go away after releasing the mouse click on the button? I'm looking for the CSS to stay changed until the user presses a different button.

Comment: In your javascript for the button click you would add the active class using, for example, $('.signup_btn').addClass('active')